# Django: name 'csrf_token' is not defined

Tags: python, django, security, csrf, django-csrf

I've a little problem with adding a `csrf_token` on my form in Django (1.2.5), though I've added all the necessary middleware classes

`{% csrf_token %}`

gives the `...name 'csrf_token' is not defined` error.

What is the problem?

Sultan

Comment: Have you got the CSRF middleware enabled in your settings.py?

Comment: @Sam Starling yes I've enabled but used deprecated one and that why the error I got.

Comment: If you solve your question yourself, you might want to answer your own question and mark it as correct. Or alternatively, I've just written an answer. That way, you're helping other people who find this page when they have a similar problem.

Comment: By the way. I didn't pay enough attention and tried to `csrf_token` as a view decorator, this is the second reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check out your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and ensure that the CSRF middleware is in there. As of Django 1.2, this was `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` — ensure that you're using the right class by reading the [Django documentation on middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/).